# gcloud \ kubectl authentication problem: forget service account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, kubectl, service-accounts, google-cloud-iam

I'm using gcloud and kubectl to handle my resources (Kubernetes, VM and so on). Everything worked find until I read some article that created a new service account and activate it via cloud. Something like this:

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=path/to/key
```

The created service account has limited permissions to few resources. When I run commands, like:

```
kubectl --namespace production get pods
```

I'm getting back response like:

> Error from server (Forbidden): pods is forbidden: User
>   "SA-USER@PROGECTNAME.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
>   cannot list resource "pods" in API group "" in the namespace
>   "production": requires one of ["container.pods.list"] permission(s).

The SA `SA-USER@PROGECTNAME.iam.gserviceaccount.com` is the service account that I created yesterday. For some reason, it took control on my default permissions and I'm locked out because this user almost has no permissions.

I tried to make the `gcloud` forget this service account without success. Things I tried:

1. Uninstall & Install of `gcloud` and `kubectl`
2. Remove the config directory ("~/.config/gcloud/")
3. `gcloud auth login`

All those tried was failed. I still getting the same message as above.

How I can make `gcloud` and `kubectl` forget this service account?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try a `gcloud auth application-default login`? You can also see the current configuration of your gcloud CLI by doing `gcloud config list`, and change some default parameter with `gcloud config set param_name param_value`. With this, you will be able to solve your issue.

Comment: Yes, this solved the problem! Thank you. Please convert it to answer and I'll mark it as "solution".

Comment: happy to hear this!! I answered  your question ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform a `gcloud auth application-default login`

You can also see the current configuration of your gcloud CLI by doing `gcloud config list`. You can change some default parameter with `gcloud config set param_name param_value`. For example (because you will use often it if you have several projects)

```
gcloud config set project MyProjectId
```

With these, you will be able to solve your issue

Answer (score 9):

## UPDATE for the new auth plugin:

Some time ago, gke adopted the [new auth plugin architecture for kubernetes](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/containers-kubernetes/kubectl-auth-changes-in-gke).

In the new plugin gke-gcloud-auth-plugin, the authentication cache is at

- macOS: `~/.kube/gke_gcloud_auth_plugin_cache`

(Please edit this answer to include locations in others operation systems.)

You can just delete that file.

---

There is a problem with the expiration of the authentication token used by kubectl.

When you choose a new user via `gcloud` and make a `kubectl` request, an authentication token is cached locally.

A workaround is to edit your ~/.kube/config and set a date in the past for the `expiry` field on the relevant user section.

Comment: This actually solved for me. Thanks!